# Is there a way to have phaser read assets from a .zip file?

Tags: javascript, html, zip, phaser-framework

To me it seems like it would be a lot more efficient to have a single HTTP request for some sort of archive file (i.e. .zip) than to have each audio/image/tilemap/etc. file downloaded via separate HTTP requests.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There's libraries that can do it

Comment: @user7951676 would you care to elaborate?

Comment: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: You can leverage texture atlases and audio sprites too. Texture atlases are also good for GPU performance if you are using WebGL.